# using triggers as resources

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, resources

I want to define triggers as resources to use them later in my controls.

Like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTrigger x:Key="Trigger1" Binding="{Binding ViewModelProperty1}" Value="Val1">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger x:Key="Trigger2" Binding="{Binding ViewModelProperty2}" Value="Val2">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    ...
</Window.Resources>
```

However, when I try to run the code, the compiler complains that IsEnabled is not a valid member. I think this is because it cannot know if the control in question will even have the property "IsEnabled". Like with styles, I think I need to somehow specifiy the TargetType (which would be, in my case, `FrameworkElement`). But how?

NOTE:

Please do not suggest to use styles instead of triggers as resources. Since a control can only have ONE style, but I need to give SEVERAL triggers to one control, styles are no option here:

In my actual code I have a Button that should have trigger 1, 2 and 4 and a TextBox that should have trigger 1 and 3 and a Label that should have trigger 2, 3 and 4... I think you get it.

Comment: And how are you going to add those triggers to your controls?

Comment: I mean you won't be able to add them to control Triggers collection anyway, only to DataTemplate, ControlTemplate or Style triggers.

Comment: @Evk I though about so: `<Button> <Button.Style> <Style> <Style.Triggers> <Trigger Binding="{Binding StaticResource="Trigger1"}"/> <Trigger Binding="{Binding StaticResource="Trigger2"}"/> ... </Style.Triggers> </Style> </Button.Style> </Button>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it like this (note how I prepend `IsEnabled` with `FrameworkElement` and also how I reference those resources from style triggers):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTrigger x:Key="Trigger1"
                 Binding="{Binding ViewModelProperty1}"
                 Value="Val1">
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.IsEnabled"
                Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger x:Key="Trigger2"
                 Binding="{Binding ViewModelProperty2}"
                 Value="Val2">
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.IsEnabled"
                Value="False" />
    </DataTrigger>
</Window.Resources>
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="Trigger1" />
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="Trigger2" />
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't believe nobode else has asked this before... And Google also didn't help either...

Comment: Indeed, I actually also didn't know (and think) about that before, but after some reasearch I've managed to find how it might be done.